# String concatenation with padded integers

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

```
var dateAndTime = DateTime.Now;
string lastTwoDigitsOfYear = DateTime.Now.ToString("yy");

int digitPlaceHolder;
digitPlaceHolder = int.Parse(lastTwoDigitsOfYear);

int stringLength = int.Parse(lastTwoDigitsOfYear);

stringLength = int.Parse(lastTwoDigitsOfYear).ToString("D4") + request.RequestId;
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is the following:

- Parsing DateTime to get the last two numbers of the year [15]
- Adding and concatenating the [15] with an Id as well as 4 zeroes padding it.

So in the end it would be: `[15][0001][id]`  This combined will result in a new variable which can be used.  I'm just having trouble converting then concatenating

> Cannot implicitly convert int to string

Is the error I'm receiving (obviously), but is there an elegant way of solving this error?

Comment: The elegant way is `.ToString()` which you've already used multiple times in your question; how did you overlook that option?

Comment: @paqo: You broke the code with your edit

Comment: I obviously didn't overlook that option, I'm more or less figuring out syntax errors.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to do `int.Parse(DateTime.Now.Year.ToString().Substring(2,2))`

Answer (score 1):

This may helps:

```
var value = string.Format("[{0}][{1:D4}][{2}]",
                           DateTime.Now.ToString("yy"), 
                           1, // or any other int value or variable
                           request.RequestId);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!  Is there an easy way to go about incrementing the padded integers?  ie: [0001...[0005]....etc?

Comment: @kzisme create and `int` variable and put it in a loop then increment that variable and replace it it in this code with the `1` literal.